# Too many output arguments in simple function

Tags: matlab

I defined a function f1 in `f1.m`:

```
function [a b]= f1(x)
a= x^4-x-10
b= e^(-x) - sin(x)
end
```

Now I want to have the vallue of `x0^4-x0-10` with`x0=3` but the expression

```
x0=3
disp(f1(x0)(1))
```

leads the error

```
Indexing with parentheses '()' must appear as the last operation of a valid
indexing expression.
```

**Where am I wrong?**

Comment: Your title doesn't fit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how your title and your question match together.

I leave aside the issue with "too many output arguments" and concentrate on the indexing.

Generally, you cannot directly index a result of a function.

You have to do

```
x0 = 3
res = f1(x0)
disp(res(1))
```

But as your result will be scalar anyway, you just can do

```
disp(res(1))
```

because `res` will be `230`.

Another way to go could be

```
x0 = 3
[res1 res2] = f1(x0)
```

but here as well your `a` result will land in `res1` and `b` in `res2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `struct` type as output like below

```
function [r]= f1(x)
r.a= x^4-x-10;
r.b= e^(-x) - sin(x);
end
```

then with `x0 = 3` you will obtain

```
>> disp(f1(x0).a)
 68
```

Comment: Since both results are the same size and type as `x`, going to a struct is an unnecessary complication in my opinion. Better to have it as a 2D matrix. (Since this code actually doesn't work for vector inputs, it would even be a 2 element vector)

Comment: @Adriaan yes, agree